# Result Set Management for Last Page (Reversed RSM)

Tags: xmpp

I'm now developing an apps with message history retrieval based on [XEP-0136](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html) with Openfire Server.

I've read that message history retrieval can be combined with Result Set Management (RSM)-[XEP-0059](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0059.html).

We can delimit the number of message retrieval request by setting `max` attribute of RSM like this:

```
<iq type='get' id='juliet1'>
  <list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'
        with='juliet@capulet.com'>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
      <max>5</max>
    </set>
  </list>
</iq>
```

This should return the first 5 chat list **from the top** (ordered by chat time ascending).

My question is how to retrieve the last 5 chat list **from the bottom**, so I can get the latest chat message **not** the first time chat.

I've seen this [Reversed RSM](https://gist.github.com/legastero/4458101) standard suggestion, like this:

```
<iq type='get' id='juliet1'>
  <list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'
        with='juliet@capulet.com'>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
      <max>5</max>
      <before />
      <reversed />
    </set>
  </list>
</iq>
```

But this standard seems not yet implemented.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0059.html#last), the stanza is like this:

```
<iq type='get' id='juliet1'>
  <list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'
        with='juliet@capulet.com'>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
      <max>5</max>
      <before />
    </set>
  </list>
</iq>
```

You can retrieve the collection from bottom by RSM.

But seems Openfire message archiving plugin had some bugs with this RSM.

Reference: http://community.igniterealtime.org/message/230389#230389

So, the possible solution is getting count of my collection:

```
<iq type='get' id='juliet1'>
  <list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'
        with='juliet@capulet.com'>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
      <max>0</max>
    </set>
  </list>
</iq>
```

It will return:

```
<iq xmlns='jabber:client' type='result' id='juliet1' to='admin@somehost'>
  <list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
      <count>10</count>
    </set>
   </list>
</iq>
```

And I select the collection by index:

```
<iq type='get' id='juliet1'>
  <list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'
        with='juliet@capulet.com'>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
      <max>5</max>
      <index>4</index>
    </set>
  </list>
</iq>
```